# remove everything that is inside the actual tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So let's say I have the following code:

```
<div id="some_id" class="another_class" style="background-color:#000;">
    Content goes here
</div>
```

I need some jquery that will make the code above the following:

```
<div>
    Content goes here
</div>
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Quick cheat (need to know tag name, won't work on some elements): `$('#some_id').contents().unwrap().wrap('<div />');`

Comment: @WesleyMurch should be an answer

Comment: @roasted It's a poor answer, for reasons noted in my comment (among others).

Comment: @WesleyMurch it will also lose data associated with the wrapping tag, such as bound events (obviously, since you delete it and write a new one, but I think it's worth mentioning)

Comment: @WesleyMurch ya you are correct

Comment: @Lepidosteus, since you are removing the id, I think it is basically a "Kill Pill"; it will be difficult to target the `div` anyway (in this case) from other `div`'s.

Comment: @SableFoste `$e = $('#some_id'); $e.click(function(e) { /* do something */ });` If you delete the tag and rewrite it, you lose the click event. If you use the solution in the duplicate, you won't. It's "subtle" enough that someone *will* be caught by it someday (and by subtle I mean so obvious that you don't even think about it)